# How to display non-unique records from a has_many through relationship in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails app I have the following relationships:

---

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :people, :through => :jobs

end
```

---

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :person

end
```

---

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :companies, :through => :jobs

end
```

---

How can I produce a list of all **persons** *including* their respective company names, so the output is something like this:

- Elon Musk (Tesla)
- Elon Musk (Space X)
- John Doe (General Motors)
- John Doe (Microsoft)
- Michael Myers (BMW)

(Note that some persons may appear multiple times on the list since they may belong to multiple companies.)

Right now I have this class method in my Person model, however it only returns the **unique** names of the persons which is not what I want:

```
def self.options
  all.map{ |p| [ p.name, p.id ] }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by using this bunch of code ..

```
<% Person.includes(:companies).each do |person| %>
    <% person.companies.each do |company| %>
        <%= person.name %> <%= "(#{company.name})" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```